# Tabbar > Split > NavigationController results in [MasterViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance: Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am trying to extend my iPhone-Application for iPad but now hitting my head for the below error

```
[MasterViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I studied all the post about similar issue. None of them are matching with my situation. Since I have copied the code from a well-done tutorial I ret, I was convinced the code must be correct.
Read below, please:

```
    // TAB BAR
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        NSLog(@"I'm an iPad");

        // Set up SPLIT VIEW
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        // Set up splitted MASTER view
        UINavigationController *accountsMasterTVCnav = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)accountsMasterTVCnav.topViewController;
        MasterViewController *accountsTVC = [[accountsMasterTVCnav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        accountsTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        // Set up Split View DETAIL view
        UINavigationController *accountsVCnav = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
        AccountsVC *accountsVC = [accountsVCnav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

This should be just the first split view. The iPhone version works with 4 tableviews and these all should be shown splitted in the iPad-Version.
How to fix that on simple manner?

Any help would be highly appreciated ... Thanks in advance!

**EDIT1:**

I updated the delegate pointers in Master and Detail controllers. Still same result (((
Adding MasterVieWController.h contents ...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Accounts.h"
#import "AccountsMasterDelegate.h"
#import "AccountsDetailDelegate.h"

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, AccountsDetailDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredAccountsArray;
@property IBOutlet UISearchBar *accountsSearchBar;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AccountsMasterDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Accounts *selectedAccount;

@end
```

below the complete error ...

```
2014-05-24 13:41:02.114 Accounts[35652:60b] -[MasterViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c187d50
2014-05-24 13:41:02.117 Accounts[35652:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MasterViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c187d50'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d85495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001029ef99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e1665d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d76d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d76938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Accounts                            0x000000010001c1de -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 2142
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100ff53d9 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 264
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100ff5be1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1605
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100ff9a0c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010100ad4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010100b216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000100ffb086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001033fb71a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001033fb1e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d07679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d0744e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d30903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102d2fd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000100ff92e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000100ffae33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    20  Accounts                            0x0000000100013793 main + 115
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000103f3d5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Let me know pls, if any additional information necessary.
Appreciate your help!

UPDATE for @Matteo:

```
// Set up splitted MASTER view
        MasterViewController *mvc = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        UINavigationController *accountsMasterTVCnav = mvc.navigationController;
//        UINavigationController *accountsMasterTVCnav = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)accountsMasterTVCnav.topViewController;
//        MasterViewController *accountsTVC = [[accountsMasterTVCnav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        mvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: Do you actually have a navigation controller in your split view controller? Also, Apple says that a split view controller should only be used as the root view controller of the window -- it shouldn't be embedded in a tab bar controller.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Navigation Controllers are present from split view controller to master and detail. Split view controllers can be embedded in a tab bar controller. May you take a look a following excellent tutorial: [link](http://timroadley.com/2012/03/24/core-data-universal-ipad-storyboard/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ATTENTION: It is cool read all the post to understand what could be happen. But in this particular case, the situation is the UPDATE 3.*

This is the problem:

```
(id)accountsMasterTVCnav.topViewController
```

First of all that `(id)` cast doesn't need.

Second, the error says that your `accountsMasterTVCnav` is of type `MasterViewController` and it doesn't have a selector (in your case so is a `@property`) called `topViewController`.

So ask yourself:

- In what class i have that property?
- Maybe i expect that `accountsMasterTVCnav` is type of that class?

**UPDATE:**

I am watching your code:

```
UINavigationController *accountsMasterTVCnav = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)accountsMasterTVCnav.topViewController;
```

`topViewController` is a property of `UINavigationController`, but when you do:

```
UINavigationController *accountsMasterTVCnav = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

you guess that the instance returned is of type `UINavigationController`, instead is of type `MasterViewController`.

**So in `splitViewController.viewControllers` the `UINavigationController` instance is not at index 0**. You have to set the correct index. I don't know your `viewController hierarchy`.

**UPDATE 2:**

watching your screenshot in the comment below try this:

```
MasterViewController *masterViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
UINavigationController *accountsMasterTVCnav = masterViewController.navigationController;
```

and another thing. Your code is in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`? So why do you need to access to the topViewController? It will be surely the first view controller and so the MasterViewController.

So if the instance returned is `MasterViewController`, you could simply to do:

```
splitViewController.delegate = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Reviewing your project, and doing a couple of test i guess that in **storyboard there is probably a bug**. This is one of the reason because i don't use storyboard.

In your code you have:

```
TabBarController
    SplitViewController
        UINavigationController *
            MasterViewController
        UINavigationController
    UINavigationController *
    UINavigationController *
    UINavigationController *
```

But what's happen is it takes 4 `NavigationController` (see the ***** above):

[image]

For this reason when you do:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

you are obtaining an `UINavigationController` instance..**(the first *)** and doing:

```
[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

obviously you obtain directly the `MasterViewController`.

And for this reason when you do:

```
[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

it crash..because there is just the `masterViewController` in that the navigation stack.

You correctly connected the `viewControllers` to the `tabViewController`.
I think this is an Apple bug...really absurd.

My suggest is to rewrite all with NIB or by code..i know is expensive..have also a look on the web about this problem.

Enjoy!